# Error while importing Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am facing error while importing Keras.
Below is the error trace:

`Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "recognize.py", line 8, in <module>
    import keras
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 87, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/framework_lib.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import Graph
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 54, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import app
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import flags
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/flags.py", line 33, in <module>
    disclaim_key_flags()  # pylint: disable=undefined-variable
NameError: name 'disclaim_key_flags' is not defined`

This was found in RaspberryPi 3 Model B. OS: Raspbian Strech

Comment: The error got resolved after reinstalling absl-py.

Answer (score 1):

pip install --upgrade pip setuptools  work for me.